# using read.xlsx on R yield errors

Tags: r, r-xlsx

I'm trying to run a line of code in R with read.xlsx taken from xlsx package.
it used to work fine but something has changed but I'm not sure what.

```
 df_sheet <- xlsx::read.xlsx(lane_info, sheetIndex = 1, startRow=5 ,colIndex = 1:8,as.data.frame=TRUE, header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # read first sheet
```

the Error is:

```
> Error in .jcall(cell, "I", "getCellType") :    method getCellType with
> signature ()I not found
```

Comment: does it work with  the openxlsx::read.xlsx? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/openxlsx/versions/4.2.3/topics/read.xlsx

Comment: openxlsx::read.xlsx seems to work... is there a way to use xlsx?